# PHP / Codeigniter Nestable List

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

Simple issue for someone to solve I hope, (I have re written this), I have a table with pages each page record has a parent_id I need to output all of the pages nested correctly under their parent page. I have managed to get the output to show two levels but I am now stuck at this point.

The eventual aim is to use [JQuery Nestable](http://dbushell.github.io/Nestable/) to allow my user to re-order the pages and set new parents.

**EDIT**

Controller:

```
public function navigation() {
    if($this->session->userdata('logged_in')) {

        $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
        $data['auid'] = $session_data['user_user_id'];
        $data['userName'] = $session_data['user_fullname'];
        $data['gravatar'] = gravatar($session_data['user_email'], 30, FALSE);

        $pages = $this->admin_m->getAllTopPages();
        foreach ($pages as $p) {
            $pid = $p->page_id;
            $children = $this->admin_m->getAllChildPages($pid);
            if($children) {
                $p->children = $children;
            }
        }


        $data['pages'] = $pages;
        $data['current'] = 'navigation';
        $this->load->view('admin/partials/header_v', $data);
        $this->load->view('admin/partials/top-bar_v');
        $this->load->view('admin/partials/side-bar_v');
        $this->load->view('admin/navigation_v');
        $this->load->view('admin/partials/footer_v');
    } else {
        redirect('admin/login', 'refresh');
    }
}
```

Model:

```
public function getAllTopPages() {
    $query = $this->db->get_where('yell_page', array('page_parent_id'=>'-1'));
    return $query->result();
}

public function getAllChildPages($pid) {
    $this->db->select('page_id, page_name, page_parent_id');
    $this->db->from('yell_page');
    $this->db->where('page_parent_id =', $pid);
    $this->db->where('page_parent_id !=', '-1');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

View:

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <div class="dd" id="nestable_list_2">
        <ol class="dd-list">
        <?php
        foreach($pages as $p) {
           echo '<li class="dd-item" data-id="'.$p->page_id.'">';
              echo '<div class="dd-handle">'.$p->page_name.'</div>';
              echo '<ol class="dd-list">';
              if(isset($p->children)) {
                 foreach($p->children as $obj) {
                   echo '<li class="dd-item" data-id="'.$obj->page_id.'"><div class="dd-handle">'.$obj->page_name.'</div></li>';
                 }
              }
              echo '</ol>';
           echo '</li>';
        }
        ?>
        </ol>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am getting somewhat closer but now the issue is that I only get data on two levels this could potentially be many more.

Comment: How the way you get the data on your model if you use model to get data from the database ? send it to controller ? how the way your controller work? can yo show the code?

Comment: @Nucleo1985 added as per your request

Comment: Seem nothing wrong with that, add skype hendra_nucleo if you use skype. I'll try to help you.

Comment: @Nucleo1985 thanks for your offer however I would sooner use Stack for the solution as it may help others, I have added some view code and an update it would be great if you could post an answer on here. Thanks again!

Comment: Encode your array into `json`. Nestable uses `json`

Comment: @OkiErieRinaldi thats not the issue its the layout of multiple levels from the array

Comment: Please tell me what do you want exactly?

Comment: @OkiErieRinaldi I have re written the question

Comment: So do you want more levels? It can be achieved by looping the array as much as the level you want, and of course it's a joke.

Comment: Create a function for creating the children and you can use it to create more levels. I mean it is recursive.